# Filtro por data em lista (Django)

Tags: django, filtro

Imagine que eu tenha uma lista e um form para filtrar esta lista por data.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém tem algum exemplo de como fazer esse filtro no form?

Eu consegui isso aqui no shell, mas não sei implementar no form, no template.

```
$ ./manage.py shell
>>> from core.models import Job
>>> import datetime
>>> start_date=datetime.date(2015,8,1)
>>> end_date=datetime.date(2015,9,1)
>>> q=Job.objects.filter(data_job__range=(start_date,end_date))
>>> for i in q: i.nome_job, i.data_job
```

Dai eu tentei em `views.py`

```
p = Job.objects.all()
q = self.request.GET.get('search_box')
# buscar por job
if q is not None:
    p = p.filter(nome_job__icontains=q)
# dmin = datetime.date(2015, 8, 1)
dmin = self.request.GET.get('min_date')
dmax = self.request.GET.get('max_date')
p = p.filter(data_job__lte=dmin,data_job__gte=dmax)
```

Preciso de algo assim.

Comment: Essa filtragem ocorreria com recarga da página (i.e. invoca-se a view e renderiza o template novamente) ou sem recarga (i.e. via JavaScript)? Seu código atual na view funciona?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você deve converter a sua data antes da pesquisa:

```
from datetime import datetime

dmin = self.request.GET.get('min_date')
dmax = self.request.GET.get('max_date')
min_date = datetime.strptime(dmin, "%d/%m/%Y")
max_date = datetime.strptime(dmax, "%d/%m/%Y")

p = p.filter(data_job__gte=min_date,data_job__lte=max_date)
```